# validates_inclusion_of error validating timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I added a snippet to my code to validate that users are passing through timezones in my form correctly, but it won't work, I'm getting the following error:

```
ArgumentError in VideosController#index
An object with the method #include? or a proc, lambda or symbol is required, and must be supplied as the :in (or :within) option of the configuration hash
```

The code snippet is:

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map { |m| m.name }, :message => "is not a valid Time Zone"
```

I got it online off a blog, so I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm using rails 4 if that makes a difference. Thank you.

Full stack trace if it's relevant:

```
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/clusivity.rb:11:in `check_validity!'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validator.rb:157:in `initialize'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:89:in `new'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:89:in `block in validates_with'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:88:in `each'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/with.rb:88:in `validates_with'
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/validations/inclusion.rb:42:in `validates_inclusion_of'
app/models/user.rb:15:in `<class:User>'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19:in `current_user'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:55:in `set_user_time_zone'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:160:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:14:in `_call'
jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.1) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/pat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/pat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/pat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving it like this

```
validates_inclusion_of :time_zone, 
   :in => ActiveSupport::TimeZone.zones_map(&:name).keys, 
   :message => "is not a valid Time Zone"
```